# A Kafka Stream contains List<Employee>, I want to create a unpacked output stream with Employee objects only

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The Kafka stream contains a `List<Employee>` and I want to process the stream as the new Kafka Stream will contain the all `Employee` from the `List<Employee>.`

In nutshell I want to unpack the Employee List from existing stream and put individual Employee object into a new stream

I am trying to use the `flatMapValues(K,V)` function in Kafka Java Library.

Basically I need to unpack the `List<Employee>` and place the individual object into the Kafka Stream.

I also tried with the forEach loop on the Kafka stream but it's not working.

I saw the documentation for using the `flatMapValues()` but not sure how to use it.

Comment: Can you update your requirement with a sample input data and the expected output format?

Comment: I need to unpack the list and add each object within the list into the Kafka stream

Comment: Do you have code that you've tried? And a specific error that you are getting?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hey Actually I am trying to create a kafka stream with unpacked `Employee` objects from the existing `List<Employee>` stream, Don't to how to unpack or flat and then put them into new stream

Comment: You already wrote that in the question. I already answered that below. Again, please edit your question to include the code you've actually tried and any specific errors you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return the list from the `flatMapValues` function, it will get expanded into individual records.

You may need to add a `Produced.withValueSerde` in order to set the appropriate serializer for individual objects rather than a list of them.